# ¿Cómo unir un Slice a otro en una matriz de 3 dimensiones GOLANG?

Tags: array, go

He estado intentando realizar un ejercicio sobre el *Append* de *Slices* y me encontré con un problema en la unión.

Lo que quiero hacer en pocas palabras es crear un Array con los datos de un índice que tiene la matriz por defecto `(array1)` con los datos que tiene la matriz adicional `(array2)`, en especifico quiero unir los índices `array1[0][0][0]` con `array2[0][0][0]` crear un nuevo array `(s)` y luego sustituirlo con el índice `array1[0][0][0]` pero aun no comprendo como es que correctamente debe manejarse el *Append* para que esto suceda, sin embargo no se si haya alguna otra manera de conseguir esto ya que soy nuevo en el lenguaje pero estare abierto a sugerencias.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    array1 := [][][]int{{{1,5,6},{8,9,8}},{{4,6,3,7},{6,2,5}}}
    array2 := [][][]int{{{23321,4224,994},{89655,954444,80000}},{{436588,64322,356577,7710},{60000,26,56666}}}
    
    s := array1[0][0][:]
    s = append(s, array2[0][0][:3]...)   // Step 1
    //copy(array1[0][0][:2], s[:5]) 
    //array1(array1[0][0][:], s[:5])
            
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/brWGQ7lA-7E)

Lo que eh intentado para conseguirlo esta en comentario, de ahí no se me ocurre alguna otra manera para lograrlo.

Lo que desearía que saliera es lo siguiente:
`[[[1 5 6 23321 4224 994] [8 9 8]] [[4 6 3 7] [6 2 5]]]`

Sin embargo la matriz que me sale `s` me da lo siguiente:
`[1 5 6 23321 4224]` y aun no me explico muy bien por que cuando debería ser `[1 5 6 23321 4224 994]`.

---

**EDIT: SOLUCION POR  Hammerffall BK:**

Entre las opciones esta valido indicar `array1[0][0] = s` o bien `array1[0][0] = append(array1[0][0], array2[0][0][:3]...)` lo cual generara la salida deseada:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    array1 := [][][]int{{{1,5,6},{8,9,8}},{{4,6,3,7},{6,2,5}}}
    array2 := [][][]int{{{23321,4224,994},{89655,954444,80000}},{{436588,64322,356577,7710},{60000,26,56666}}}
    
    s := array1[0][0][:]
    s = append(s, array2[0][0][:3]...)   // Step 1
    array1[0][0] = s  // o bien array1[0][0] = append(array1[0][0], array2[0][0][:3]...)
    fmt.Println(array1)
            
}
```

Salida: `[[[1 5 6 23321 4224 994] [8 9 8]] [[4 6 3 7] [6 2 5]]]`

Comment: El código que posteaste, genera el arreglo `[1 5 6 23321 4224 994]` en `s`. lo de debes hacer es `array1[0][0] = s` y luego la impresión `fmt.Println(array1)`

Comment: Incluso esto es válido `array1[0][0] = append(array1[0][0], array2[0][0][:3]...)`

Comment: Wow como no se me ocurrio antes! olvide que las posiciones en el Append tenia que especificarlas desde su inicializacion (asi lo entiendo) ya que se tiene que enmarcar por donde debe ubicarse el valor que se debe ingresar, MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!